# Difference between this.href and $(this).attr("href")

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [this.href vs $(this).attr('href')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977049/this-href-vs-this-attrhref)

Here is my code:

```
 $(function () {
        $("a.Delete").click(function () {
            console.log(this.href);
            console.log($(this).attr("href"));
            return false;
        });
```

and here is my link

```
<a class="Delete" href="/Contact/Delete/10402">Delete</a>
```

Here is my output:

```
http://localhost:59485/Contact/Delete/10402
/Contact/Delete/10402
```

Why the difference doesn't the attr method just get the attribute. Isn't that what this.href does? Is the href property special in some way that it actually gives you the absolute url?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977049/this-href-vs-this-attrhref

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first version, `this.href` is reading the attribute directly from the javascript implementation the browser uses. This is providing you with an absolute URL as the browser is interpreting the href attribute and combining it with the current host URL.

The second, `$(this).attr("href")` is wrapping the element in a jQuery object, and then accessing the `href` attribute of the object. There is no processing on the value being returned so it is simply giving you the exact string which was in your HTML.

Answer (score 6):

HTML `a` elements have an `href` property that acts similarly to the `document.location` object. It will return the fully qualified URL of the href specified in the `[href]` attribute. Including the protocol, domain, etc.

jQuery's `attr` method gets the attribute value as-is. Behind-the-scenes it uses `getAttribute` (or equivalent).

If you wanted to get the literal attribute value in raw JS you'd use:

```
anchor.getAttribute('href');
```

If you wanted to get the fully qualified URL in jQuery you'd use:

```
$('a').prop('href'); //jQuery 1.6+
```

Answer (score 2):

`this.href` gives you the absolute URI.

`$(this).attr("href")` gives you whatever text is in the `href` attribute which may or may not be a relative URI.