# Animate div on click, Load Content into div

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic-content

I'm using the following jQuery to try and fade out a div, load an HTML page, then fade back in.  The fades are working, but it doesn't seem to be loading the HTML, and I'm not quite sure what I'm missing.  The first function is an attempt to load my first page into the div on initially visiting the site.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Content").load("Landing.html");

});

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("#Content").fadeOut(500);  
        $("#Content").load("linkLocation"); 
        $("#Content").fadeIn(500); 
    });

});
```

Basic idea of the HTML

```
<ul>
        <li>
          <a href="Contact.html">contact</a>
       </li>  

       <li>
          <a href="Portfolio.html">portfolio</a>
       </li>

        <li>
          <a href="Services.html">services</a> 
        </li> 

       <li>
          <a href="About.html">about</a>
       </li>

       <li>
          <a href="Landing.html">home</a>
       </li>      
     </ul>

<div id="Content"></div>
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT

Thanks for all the suggestions.  I've tried out each of them, and still no luck.  I must be missing something really simple, but I just can't see it ATM.

Comment: Did you check the path to the files, filenames (case etc.). As a sidenote you only need one document ready function.

Comment: Hi adeneo, thanks for the suggestion!  I keep checking that over and over, but still no luck.  Also, FWIW, if I remove the preventDefault, it takes me to the correct pages.

Answer (score 0):

`linkLocation` location is a variable not a string, so should not be enclosed in `""`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var linkLocation = this.href;
        $("#Content").fadeOut(500);  
        $("#Content").load(linkLocation ); 
        $("#Content").fadeIn(500); 
    });

});
```

Comment: Shouldn't `this.href` be `this.attr('href')`? And the whole thing can be wrapped in a single doc ready function.

Comment: @rogMaHall both will work, `this.href` will read the `href` property of the `this` dom element. try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/J4E4c/1/

Comment: Your right, however `this.href` will retrieve the full destination url, while `this.attr('href')` will only bring back what's written in the markup. Here's a good SO thread on it - [this.href vs $(this).attr('href')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977049/this-href-vs-this-attrhref). Not sure if OP has a preference, but good to know :)

Comment: Thanks!  Still no luck.  Must be something stupid I'm missing in my expanded code.

Comment: are you sure the click handler is getting called

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is.  The fade out and fade in happen appropriately on the selected div, there's just no content being loaded into it.

Comment: check the browser developer tools network tab to see whether there is any error

Comment: Ah!  Thanks!  Didn't think about that.  Looks like a Chrome issue.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Opened it up in Safari, works like a charm!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for best results you should chain the calls to make sure one is complete before the other one fires :

```
  $("#Content").fadeOut(500, function () {
        $("#Content").load(linkLocation, function () {
            $("#Content").fadeIn(500)
        });
    });
```

and yeah, fix the link attr problem as advised above.

Comment: Good point on chaining the calls.  I'll keep that in mind for this.  I tried it out, but still no luck.  Also tried the link attr suggestion, and no luck.